# Excel VBA to MATLAB conversion to create a diagram with one Y axis and two X axes

Tags: vba, matlab, code-conversion

I'd like to convert a diagram-creating-Excel-VBA Code to a Matlab script, so that I can manipulate an Excel file without dealing with excel, and by the Matlab script.Thanks in advance.
VBA code is as follows:

    **`Sub qwer()
    '
    ' qwer Makro
    ' This macro creates a diagram with an X axis and two Y axes
        Sheets("Loadcase1").Select
        Range("D39:E39").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Overview").Select
        Range("B60").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("H15").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Min Film Thickness mean"""
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Overview!$C$29:$H$29"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Overview!$C$40:$H$40"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Sommerfeld Number"""
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Overview!$C$29:$H$29"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Overview!$C$43:$H$43"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""Min Film Thickness Min"""
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=Overview!$C$29:$H$29"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=Overview!$B$60:$B$65"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""Min Film Thickness Max"""
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=Overview!$C$29:$H$29"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "=Overview!$C$60:$C$65"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    End Sub`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question. Regarding matlab code is as follows:

```
%% Excel Diagramm Versuch2
clc; clear all; close all;
excel = actxserver('excel.application');
excel.Visible = 1;
wkbk = excel.Workbooks.Open('Z:\...file directory...\V1.xlsx');
wkbk.ActiveSheet;
wkbk.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select;
wkbk.ActiveChart.ChartType = 'XlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers';
% qwer makro Anfang
wkbk.Sheet.Item('Tabelle2').Select;
wkbk.Sheet.Item('Tabelle1').Select;
wkbk.ActiveChart;
% Set the x-axis
Axes = invoke(excel.ActiveChart,'Axes',1); 
set(Axes,'HasTitle',1); 
set(Axes.AxisTitle,'Caption','Revolution[1/min]')
% Set the y-axis
Axes = invoke(excel.ActiveChart,'Axes',2); 
set(Axes,'HasTitle',1); 
set(Axes.AxisTitle,'Caption','Film Thickness[µm]')
% Give the Chart a title 
excel.ActiveChart.HasTitle = 1; 
excel.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = 'Film Thickness-Revolution';
invoke(excel.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection,'NewSeries');
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = 'Min Film Thickness mean';
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = 'Tabelle1!$A$5:$A$10';
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = 'Tabelle1!$B$5:$B$10';
invoke(excel.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection,'NewSeries');
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = 'Sommerfeld Number';
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = 'Tabelle2!$A$5:$A$10';
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = 'Tabelle2!$B$5:$B$10';
wkbk.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2;
pause(20)
wkbk.Close;
excel.Quit; 
close excel
```